# Nuxt 3 handle 401 error and refresh user token

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

What is the best way to handle 401 error, refresh user token and repeat request using Nuxt 3 useFetch composable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with the help of axios instance interceptors

```
export function useFetchWithAuth(url, options) {
  const instance = axios.create();

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // Refresh the access token.
        

        // Retry the original request.
        return instance(error.config);
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  const fetch = useFetch(instance);

  return async ({ ...opts }) => {
    const { data } = await fetch(url, {
      ...options,
      ...opts,
    });

    return data;
  };
}
```

Then you can use in component class:

```
<script setup>
const fetch = useFetchWithAuth();

    async function makeRequest() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/users');

    }
</script>
```

Hope this help.